# How can i define a JUnit test in one maven project and have it run in another maven project?

Tags: java, maven, junit, cdi, dependency-management

I want to create some architecture validation components, that will be later used in architecture description components.
My first idea is to create validations as JUnit test, and then declare test suites using those tests (ideally I would not even have to declare those test and have some kind of dependency injection to have all the tests in the test suite).
How can I do that using JUnit and Java CDI ?

Comment: Are we talking about [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise No I'm trying to validate other kind of elements. Examples are : each container must be linked to a GitHub project having a readme, or each containe rmust be linked to a deployed docker container which version is the same than the dependency

Comment: The test classpath of a module is not included in any classpath of modules that depend on it in Maven. In other words the tests of a module are private to it. The only way to create a testing library is to put the test classes in the main code, i.e. `src/main`, not `src/test`. This is legitimate since this is a testing library: other modules should depend on it in scope `test`, so there is no chance of including test classes in a production build. (E.g. take a look at the code of Mockito, which is a testing library itself: the classes are under `src/main`.)